# Why did I lose 40 reputation for a bounty question with 4 upvotes?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I have a question that I placed a bounty on. It recieved 4 upvotes and 0 downvotes as shown in the votes history, yet my recent reputation shows -40 for the question. Why is this?

[image]

Comment: well, you spent 50 rep on the bounty, right?

Comment: that particular -40 is likely to be: -50 (from you putting a bounty up) + 10 (2 of the 4 upvotes, the other 2 were probably already seen by you earlier)

Comment: You can get 2 points back by deleting the javascript answer shown below :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I know lol. The question is less about wanting the rep and more about understanding what is happening. From the comments it appears that the bounty rep is deducted and summed with upvotes - although, I would have thought they would be listed separately, like -50, +5, +5.

Comment: no they're merged if happened the same day. convenient when you check your rep on your phone. you have the detail of the events in your profile.

Comment: The added coincidence of 4 votes and -40 also threw me for a loop :)